# Why does JavaScript behave like synchronous without web API call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom-events

I know JavaScript is synchronous by nature. So that when I call a function with web API It performs synchronously:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('1');
}, 2000);

console.log('2');
```

it will print  '2' then '1'.

But when I run a loop like for loop and increase the iteration it executes synchronously:

```
var first = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<=100000000;i++){
        if(i==100000000){
            console.log('first')
        };
    };
};

var second = function() {
    console.log('second')
};

var a = function() {
    first();
    second();
}

a();
```

It will print the first second respectively.

> So, is JavaScript performing synchronously with native code?

Comment: _"javaScript is asynchronous by nature"_ - No it isn't.

Comment: @Turnip would you please send some link where I can look. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at what? `    `

Comment: Javascript is not asynchronous by nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know that

JavaScript is sync and async functionality depends on your functions implementation.

It has an event loop and it executes synchronously but whenever it will get the async function( the function which takes callback i.e setTimeout ,fs.readFile() etc) which is not the part of the javaScript then, 
**It put the function into the queue and invoke the queue function after all the native code(which is in current scope) execute then it pop the queue and invoke the functions.**

[image]

and setTimeout explicitly set up an asynchronously timed callback to the function.

check this [javaScript Async behavior](http://:https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj02vL4tuHNAhUGpY8KHVsoAmcQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8aGhZQkoFbQ&usg=AFQjCNHH9E_FFETO0UU8a5VSvAHYpYD-XA) ;

Answer (score 7):

The first example is asynchronous because you've explicitly *asked* it to be asynchronous by using `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` (and its relation `setInterval`) explicitly set up an *asynchronous* timed callback to the function you pass them.

The remaining examples don't use anything that creates asynchronousness like `setTimeout` (and ajax and such) do, so naturally it's synchronous.

> I know javaScript is asynchronous by nature

No, JavaScript (the language) is **synchronous** by nature. Literally the only asynchronous aspect of JavaScript was added in ES2015 and relates to when the callback passed into a promise's `then` or `catch` is called. That's it. `setTimeout`, for instance, is not part of JavaScript; it's part of the host environment where JavaScript is largely used (browsers). (It's also part of a couple of non-browser host environments, like NodeJS.)

JavaScript is primarily used in an environment that encourages asynchronous operations (browsers) where it's used to respond to user events (asynchronous), ajax completions (asynchronous), and timer callbacks (asynchronous), but the *language* is almost entirely synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

JS is **event-driven**, this is why you think its async.. But it only has async features..

`for` loop does not have any event-callbacks, so its just sync

Comment: As far as I know the Array.forEach method is synchronous.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini true, I remove it